# pythonのprintのエラーについて

Tags: python, python3

[pipを使わずwindows10にtesseractとPyOCRをインストールする方法](https://haitenaipants.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/06/02/193554) のサイトを参考に
以下のプログラムを実行するとエラーが出てしまいます。どうしてでしょうか？

**エラー内容**

```
    File "<ipython-input-15-8474a031face>", line 4
    print("No OCR tool found")
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

**プログラム文**

```
tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
if len(tools) == 0:
print("No OCR tool found")
sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: 元の記事を良く見ると判りますが、`print`と`sys.exit`の行は、先頭に3桁?の空白文字が入っています。 これは`if`文の条件が真のときだけ実行されるようにするための`indentation`です。質問の状況では`if`文があるのに、真の時に実行される文が無いのでエラーになっているわけです。

Comment: 無事実行させることができました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

**1点目**
リンク先のソースをそのままコピペした場合、`print` と `sys.exit` の前がそれぞれ**全角スペース**になっています。

**2点目**
Pythonではインデントが非常に重要です。プログラムが何をしているのかを見極めましょう。

「結果が無かったらprintで文字を出力してプログラムを終了する」なので、それぞれの命令を
インデント(字下げ)する必要があります。

```py
if len(tools) == 0:
  print("No OCR tool found")
  sys.exit(1)
```

**3点目**
リンク先では説明のため段落が分かれていますが、エラーメッセージを見る限りあなたが実行したソースではモジュールのインポート記述が足りていません。正しくは以下の様になるはずです。

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders

tools = pyocr.get_available_tools() 

if len(tools) == 0:
  print("No OCR tool found")
  sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
if len(tools) == 0:
  print("No OCR tool found")        # two space before code
sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

このエラーを日本語に訳すと「インデントのエラー：ここにインデントされたブロックが入るはずです」というものです。

次のコードにするとこのエラーが出なくなるはずです。

```py
tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
if len(tools) == 0:
    print("No OCR tool found")
    sys.exit(1)
```

このプログラムでは、もし `len(tools) == 0` が成り立つのであれば、`print("No OCR tool found")` と `sys.exit(1)` というプログラムを実行します。成り立っていなければ何もしません。

Python ではこのように、if文の条件が成り立っていたら何を実行するかを、行の最初に空白（インデント）を入れることで表現します。